# How do I clone a git repo into hg repo as a submodule?

Tags: git, mercurial, git-submodules

Have searched around, and was pointed to this: https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/Subrepository

But thats a hg within a hg. (hg aka mercurial)

I need the steps to clone the git repo into my current hg repo as a submodule.

By the way, I have both hg and git installed.

So I'm wondering, can I simply go into my hg repo's folder, and do a `git clone` there?

So hg alone, will manage the whole application (including the git repo), while git manages, its own repo.

Will there be any implications?
Is this method the so called git submodule within hg?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a git subrepo.  Have a look at https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/Subrepository#Git_subrepositories

Comment: ah..my bad..only scanned the big headers. thanks.  

but is there a difference between using hg's method, and my theoretical method?